# Passing Static variable value as a parameter in instance method

Tags: java, parameter-passing, static-methods, instance-methods

Can we pass a static variable value as a parameter in an instance method in Java?

```java
static webdriver driver = webdriver.driver.chrome();

public void setup(webdriver ldriver) {
  this.driver=ldriver;
}
```

Can a pass static variable value to method?

Comment: No you can't. I'm not fully understand your question, but your code is wrong. You're not passing static variable as a parameter in that method, but you're assigning parameter value `ldriver` into the static variable.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Class names should be written in PascalCase, and method or variable names in camelCase.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide a little more detail of what exactly you want to achieve? Nothing prevents you from passing a variable to a method, as long as they're in scope.